# Use sed/awk to delete a line if the following line does not match

Tags: regex, bash, sed, awk

I have a list of data as follows:

```
Account Number: 11111
Domain        : domain.com
     Quantity: 1
     Quantity: 2
    Processor: Intel Xeon E5-1650 V2 3.5GHZ, Hexa Core
    SERVERCHASSIS: Standard - Single PSU - No Hot Swap Bays

Account Number: 54321
Domain        : domain0.com
     Quantity: 1
    Processor: Intel Xeon E3-1240 V1 3.3Ghz, Quad Core
    SERVERCHASSIS: Standard - Single PSU - No Hot Swap Bays
     Quantity: 1

Account Number: 12345
Domain        : domain1.com
     Quantity: 1
```

I would like to use sed/awk to delete all entries of "Quantity: X" that are not followed by "Processor:" on the next line. I would also like to remove "Account Number: XXXXX" and "Domain:" lines if the lines following do not contain both "Quantity: X" and "Processor:". This in turn would change the above data to:

```
Account Number: 11111
Domain        : domain.com
     Quantity: 2
    Processor: Intel Xeon E5-1650 V2 3.5GHZ, Hexa Core
    SERVERCHASSIS: Standard - Single PSU - No Hot Swap Bays

Account Number: 54321
Domain        : domain0.com
     Quantity: 1
    Processor: Intel Xeon E3-1240 V1 3.3Ghz, Quad Core
    SERVERCHASSIS: Standard - Single PSU - No Hot Swap Bays
```

Can anyone provide a way to complete this task using sed or awk or a combination of both?

Comment: You NEVER need a combination of sed and awk since anything sed can do, awk can do. Also you should never use sed for jobs that aren't 100% constrained to individual lines of text as that will involve sed language constructs that became obsolete in mid-1970 when awk was invented and so the result will always be harder to read and much less robust than an awk script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ RS=""; FS="\n" }
/Quantity:/ && /Processor:/ {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ( ! (($i ~ /Quantity:/) && ($(i+1) !~ /Processor:/)) ) {
            print $i
        }
    }
    print ""
}
$ 
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Account Number: 11111
Domain        : domain.com
     Quantity: 2
    Processor: Intel Xeon E5-1650 V2 3.5GHZ, Hexa Core
    SERVERCHASSIS: Standard - Single PSU - No Hot Swap Bays

Account Number: 54321
Domain        : domain0.com
     Quantity: 1
    Processor: Intel Xeon E3-1240 V1 3.3Ghz, Quad Core
    SERVERCHASSIS: Standard - Single PSU - No Hot Swap Bays
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Erf... Should have read the question before answering.
This one should work, hopefully

```
BEGIN { 
        OFS=RS
        FS="\n"
        RS= ""
    }

    {
        selected = 0
        drop = 0
        for (i = 1; i <= NF ; i++)
        {
            if ($i ~ "Quantity:")
            {
                if ($(i+1) ~ "Processor:") selected = 1
                else  drop++
            }
            $i = $(i+drop)
        }
        if (selected) print
    }
```

cmd

```
gawk -f processor.awk processor.txt
```

output

```
Account Number: 11111
Domain        : domain.com
     Quantity: 2
    Processor: Intel Xeon E5-1650 V2 3.5GHZ, Hexa Core
    SERVERCHASSIS: Standard - Single PSU - No Hot Swap Bays

Account Number: 54321
Domain        : domain0.com
     Quantity: 1
    Processor: Intel Xeon E3-1240 V1 3.3Ghz, Quad Core
    SERVERCHASSIS: Standard - Single PSU - No Hot Swap Bays
```

Comment: You should try it. I don't think it's in the ballpark of what the OP was looking for.

Comment: @Ed Yep, should have read the question till the end before answering. This solution avoids duplicating the keywords, though it makes little difference in the end.